# mutate(across()) with two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I want to mutate the chr columns into factors, but exclude the first 15 columns (some of which are chr). I can only seem to mutate everything with `mutate(across(where(is.character))...` or `mutate(across(.cols = -c(1:15))...`. Additionally, I want to save the changes into the dataset (`%<>%`) so I cannot just select out 1:15 first. For example, how would you
`starwars%<>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)` but excluding `name`.

Comment: Yep it a reprex, thanks as always for the solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
starwars %<>%
    mutate(across(c(where(is.character),-(1:5)), factor))
```